# How to fetch only selected attributes of an entity using Spring JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot (1.3.3.RELEASE) and Hibernate JPA in my project. My entity looks like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "rule")
public class RuleVO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 128, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "tag", length = 256)
    private String tag;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rule", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<RuleOutputArticleVO> outputArticles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rule", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<RuleInputArticleVO> inputArticles;
}
```

My repository looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface RuleRepository extends JpaRepository<RuleVO, Long> {
}
```

In some cases I need to fetch only **id** and **name** attributes of entity RuleVO. How can I achieve this? I found a notice it should be doable using Criteria API and Projections but how? Many thanks in advance. Vojtech

Comment: I can't be done, all you can do is Lazy load the collections.  I would say there is no performance benefit of pulling back data selectively.

Comment: See 19.1.7 https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html which essentially states that, in line with the comment above, for non-collection fields it is doable but you are wasting your time.

Comment: Spring Data Projection is the best solution for such problem. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

As has been pointed out to me, I'm lazy and this can very well be done hence I'm updating my answer after having looked around the web for a proper one.

Here's an example of how to get *only* the id's and *only* the names:

```
@Repository
public interface RuleRepository extends JpaRepository<RuleVO, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT r.id FROM RuleVo r where r.name = :name") 
    List<Long> findIdByName(@Param("name") String name);

    @Query("SELECT r.name FROM RuleVo r where r.id = :id") 
    String findNameById(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

Hopefully this update proves helpful

---

**Old Answer:**

Only retrieving the specific attributes name/id is not possible as this is not how spring was designed or any SQL database for that matter as you always select a row which is an entity.

What you CAN do is query over the variables in the entity, for instance:

```
@Repository
public interface RuleRepository extends JpaRepository<RuleVO, Long> {

    public RuleVo findOneByName(String name);
    public RuleVo findOneByNameOrId(String name, Long id);
    public List<RuleVo> findAllByName(String name);
    // etc, depending on what you want
}
```

You can modify these however you want w.r.t. your needs. You can call these methods directly via the autowired repository

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ Section 5.3 for more options and examples

Comment: Thats not true. Sql is all about fetching columns of rows. `select * from mytable` is just our developer laziness ;)

Comment: You're correct. Haven't actually written a query in a while =D `select field from table`, voila: column

Comment: Doesn't work if you have relationships in that entity

Answer (score 11):

```
interface IdOnly{
    String getId();
}

@Repository
public interface RuleRepository extends JpaRepository<RuleVO, Long> {
    public List<IdOnly> findAllByName(String name);
}
```

I notice that this is a very old post, but if someone is still looking for an answer, try this. It worked for me.

Comment: Curious to see if this worked, since it is an answer that avoids writing SQL.  I'll revisit when I can

Comment: Projection works. One note - interface has to be public, it has to in separate file https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: I just checked it. It looks like the query selects all fields, so this is not a real solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can also define custom constructor to fetch specific columns using JPQL.

Example:

> Replace {javaPackagePath} with complete java package path of the class
>   use as a constructor in JPQL.

```
public class RuleVO {
   public RuleVO(Long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
   }
}


@Repository
public interface RuleRepository extends JpaRepository<RuleVO, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT new {javaPackagePath}.RuleVO(r.id, r.name) FROM RuleVo r where r.name = :name") 
    List<RuleVO> findIdByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution is simpler and is recommended especially for associated entities. Note: while we've already imported the entity, no need to specify its package path in query annotation.

Comment: Thank you. I tried our solution, but I got table is not mapped error. I always use nativeQuery=true, but in your case it is not a nativeQuery so I removed that so I got error like table is not mapped. How for you is working without using nativeQuery=true. Any Help...

Comment: @Prakash Have you actually mapped your table using `@Entity`? See, if you have the only `@Table` which only works for native queries. You might need both annotations if you are using JPQL/HQL and native queries both.  I might need more information about the error and the Query you are using, then I can help better.

Comment: @AbhilekhSingh Thanks for your response. I fixed my issue. Actually in JPQL instead of referring entity name, I just referred table name as it only works in native query. When I changed all my table and column names to entity classname and class variables it started working correctly.

Comment: @AbhilekhSingh For the above case, you told to create the different constructors that need to require to fetch the data from table. For eg. If I need 2 column values from table then the constructor should contain two parameters and so on.. But If have around 20 columns in my table, for the first query I need firstname and lastname so both are strings I create one constructor with two parameters as string and get that data, for next query I need state and city that comes under string.  Continued in next Command.....

Comment: @AbhilekhSingh    But this case I cannot able to create another constructor with 2 parameters as string. Because I already created one constructor for firstname and lastname which also 2 parameters as string. What I should in this situation. Any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can achieve it with projections. You have many ways to apply them:

If you could upgrade to Spring Data Hopper, it provides an easy to use support for projections. See how to use them in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections).

Otherwise, first of all create a DTO with the attributes you want to load, something like:

```
package org.example;

public class RuleProjection {

    private final Long id;

    private final String name;

    public RuleProjection(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Of course, you could use Lombok annotations also.

Then, you can use in the JPQL queries like this:

```
select new org.example.RuleProjection(rule.id, rule.name) from RuleVO rule order by rule.name
```

Another option, if you want to avoid using DTO class names in your queries, is to implement your own query method using QueryDSL. With Spring Data JPA, you have to:

- Create a new interface with the new method. Ex:

  ```
  public interface RuleRepositoryCustom {
     public List<RuleProjection> findAllWithProjection();
  }
  ```
- Change your repository to extend the new interface. Ex:

  ```
  public interface RuleRepository extends JpaRepository<RuleVO, Long>, RuleRepositoryCustom {
  ...
  ```
- Create an implementation of the Custom repository using the Spring Data JPA QueryDSL support. You have to previously generate the Q clases of QueryDSL, using its Maven plugin. Ex:

  ```
  public class RuleRepositoryImpl {

      public List<RuleProjection> findAllWithProjection() {
          QRuleVO rule = QRuleVO.ruleVO;
          JPQLQuery query = getQueryFrom(rule);     
          query.orderBy(rule.name.asc());
          return query.list(ConstructorExpression.create(RuleProjection.class, rule.id, rule.name));
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: The `JPQL` with the `new Projection(...)` did the trick for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using @Query annotation(HQL).

Please refer to the Spring docs below:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

(search for @Query in spring document)